# Insert into select not working no idea why

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

Is it possible to do this?

```
insert into cart(cartid,rowid,productname) select max(cartid)+1 from cart, 2, "hello"
```

i want to insert my own values of rowid and productname

Comment: Have you typo'ed the select i.e. `SELECT MAX(cartid)+1, 2, 'hello' FROM cart`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you phrase the query:

```
insert into cart (cartid, rowid, productname)
    select max(cartid) + 1, 2, 'hello'
    from cart;
```

However, this is the wrong way to have an auto-incremented `cartid`.  Instead, define the column to be auto-incrementing and simply do:

```
insert into cart (rowid, productname)
    select 2, 'hello'
    from cart;
```

The database takes care of the assignment automatically.

Comment: thanks it works! By the way do you know if this works? I'm getting an error saying that you cant declare 2 tables. update cart set productname='hey' where cartid=(select max(cartid) from cart)

Comment: MySQL does not allow you to reference the table being updated in most other places in a query.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is not correct:

```
insert into cart(cartid,rowid,productname)
select max(cartid)+1, 2, "hello" from cart
```

another problem is that if the cart table is empty, then max(cartid) will be null and you cannot initialize your table, so you have to use coalesce:

```
insert into cart(cartid,rowid,productname)
select coalesce(max(cartid)+1, 1), 2, "hello" from cart
```

but why you want to do something like that? Can't you use a auto_increment column?

Comment: Thanks! Hmm, its complicated.. i would love to use the auto_increment if i could too haha